# Update collection when remove the same entity from other collection

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have 4 classes entities: CtPersonaFirma, CtFirmaDocumento and CtContrato. A person may sign several contracts and a contract can be signed by multiple people.

CtPersonaFirma: Contains persons authorized to sign.

CtContrato: Contains contracts

CtFirmaDocumento: The relationship between the two tables above.

When I delete a person CtPersonaFirma table for cascading deletes CtFirmaDocumento table where there is reference to the person removed, but in the collection ctFirmaDocumentoCollection of the entity CtContrato not updated.

```
public class CtContrato implements Serializable {
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_contrato")
private Integer idContrato;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ctContrato", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<CtFirmaDocumento> ctFirmaDocumentoCollection;


public class CtPersonaFirma implements Serializable {
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_persona")
private Integer idPersona;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ctPersonaFirma")
private Collection<CtFirmaDocumento> ctFirmaDocumentoCollection;

public class CtFirmaDocumento implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
protected CtFirmaDocumentoPK ctFirmaDocumentoPK;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_persona_ref", referencedColumnName = "id_persona", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private CtPersonaFirma ctPersonaFirma;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_contrato", referencedColumnName = "id_contrato", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private CtContrato ctContrato;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA requires the application to maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships.  When you make changes to one side, JPA will not maintain the other side for you, and your cached entities will be out of synch with what is in the database.  Depending on which side you change, those changes might not get persisted in the database either.

In this case, when you remove the CtFirmaDocumento objects, you should also remove all references to those objects in any CtContrato that might reference it.

An alternative in this case would be to force a refresh of any CtContrato objects after the changes have been flushed or commited, but it is usually better to fix the references directly to avoid problems with this relationship later.

Comment: force a refresh, what kind of problem can get?

Comment: It is a database hit access, so it has performance costs.  Refresh on an entity with uncommited changes will revert those changes, which is why I think it is easier to maintain both sides, or just not map the 1:M at all.